# Yii2 - onCondition added to where part of child query

Tags: php, yii, yii2, rbac

I noticed in v2.1, the onCondition is being added to the where condition -https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/2.1/framework/db/ActiveQuery.php#L202

I do not know why, but this is affecting me from being able to use my relation as below.

I am working on the RBAC module for a new project. I am not using Yii2's default because it is a SaaS system, roles have to be defined per `account`, we would rather use `id` instead of name as unique keys and we do not like the naming conventions.

I have tables `permissions`, `privileges` and `roles`

`privileges - [id, name]` - things you can do in the system
`roles - [account_id, id, name]` - different roles per account
`permissions - [parent_type, parent_id, child_type, child_id]` - mapping of roles to privileges, roles to roles, and privileges to privileges.

Problem now is i need to `findAll` `permissions` and get the child / parent having the appropriate objects.

For parent, I have

```
public function getParentPrivilege($type) {
    return $this->hasOne(Privilege::className(), ['id' => 'parent_id'])->onCondition('parent_type = "privilege"');
}

public function getParentRole() {
    return $this->hasOne(Role::className(), ['id' => 'parent_id'])->onCondition('parent_type = "role"');
}

public function getParent(){
    if($this->parentPrivilege)
        return $this->parentPrivilege;
    else
        return $this->parentRole;
}
```

Then i do a find by:

```
$permissions = \app\models\Permission::find()
    ->joinWith(['parentRole','parentPrivilege'])
    ->all();
```

Problem is, `onCondition` is used in the SQL on condition since I used `joinWith` BUT, the `onCondition` is still being added to the `where` clause of the parent queries as seen below.

```
SELECT `permissions`.* FROM `permissions` 
LEFT JOIN `roles` ON (`permissions`.`parent_id` = `roles`.`id`) AND (parent_type = "role") 
LEFT JOIN `privileges` ON (`permissions`.`parent_id` = `privileges`.`id`) AND (parent_type = "privilege")

SELECT * FROM `roles` WHERE (`id` IN ('3', '1', '4', '2', '25')) AND (parent_type = "role")
SELECT * FROM `privileges` WHERE (`id` IN ('5')) AND (parent_type = "privilege")
```

WHY?!!!

Makes no sense to add `AND (parent_type = "role")` and `AND (parent_type = "privilege")` to the following relation queries

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 2):

As we see onCondition doesn't affect `joinWith()`.

Try to remove onCondition from relations' declations and to rewrite the query like this

```
    $permissions = \app\models\Permission::find()
        ->joinWith([
            'parentRole' => function ($query) {
                $query->andOnCondition('parent_type = "role"');
            },
            'parentPrivilege' => function ($query) {
                $query->andOnCondition('parent_type = "privilege"');
            }
        ])->all();
```

Comment: interesting. will test. but *very* bad if i have to remove from relations. the implication is every part of the code using that relation will have to be aware of using `joinWith` and the extra `onCondition`s

Comment: You can inherit a new query class from \yii\db\ActiveQuery class and use it in your model.
For this your need to redefine find() method in your model.
Then you can create new method in this query class and put there joinWith logic.
In this case you will be able to call \app\models\Premission::find()->withParent()->all()

Comment: This also produces same result, onCondition applying to all parts of the query, as it says in docs. Still trying to figure out how to solve.